# How to change NavigationBar title in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Hey so i am a bit stuck on this one - i've had a look around and can't find anything specific to my question so feel free to redirect me:

I have set up a MapViewController navigation bar to change title depending on what table cell is clicked but this MapViewController is also available as a tab bar item that will show a larger map BUT when no table cell is clicked it will not show any title.

For the TableViewController.m:

```
@interface FirstTableViewController () {

    NSArray *locations;
}

@end

@implementation FirstTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bondi", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [locations count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    //Uncomment to have array auto-name table as oposed to custom designs
    //cell.textLabel.text = [locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapViewer"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MapViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.resultsName = [locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

And for the MapViewController.h declared properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *resultsName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *locationName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultsLabel;
```

Finally the MapViewController.m:

```
@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize resultsName;
@synthesize resultsLabel;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Showing %@", resultsName];
    _locationName.title = resultsName;


}
```

Any hints/tips at all would be appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the title property on your MapViewController. So in `viewDidLoad` you could do something like `self.title = self.resultsName;` or just set it directly in your `prepareForSegue` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"the title";
```